# Turn datepicker valuestring to ToLongDateString

Tags: string, datetime, datepicker, windows-phone-8

Just want to start of that this whole question starts with this article:
http://transoceanic.blogspot.se/2011/08/wp7-create-datepicker-control.html

So i have done as in the article and now want to make the value of the selected date to a LongDateString:

The value_Changed event look like this:

```
void datePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       var datevalue = this.datePicker.ValueString;
       MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show(datevalue, "Date", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

Is there any way to make this to a LongDateString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after reading the documentation. Here is how i did:

```
string final;
string datevalue = this.datePicker.ValueString;

DateTime result;
result = DateTime.Parse(datevalue);

final = result.ToLongDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what format ValueString is, but you need to parse it to a DateTime before you can use LongDateString. See [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) or [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) for more info. Then you can use the result and call LongDateString.